# Talend string max length

Tags: string, talend, data-integration

With Talend Data Integration , I read a csv file. I make a transformation with a tmap and I write in another file. My fields must not exceed 40 characters. My repository I set length to 40, but I have no warning when my chain beyond .

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a tSchemaComplianceCheck component to filter out rows of data that don't match your defined schema.